# Are Java Strings stored differently in heap based on how they are being constructed?

Tags: java, string, jvm, java-10, jnienv

I'm working on a code base which uses JNI techniques for modeling native methods.

Here is the segment of the native peer method used for `java.lang.String#equals(Object)`

```
@MJI
public boolean equals__Ljava_lang_Object_2__Z (MJIEnv env, int objRef, int argRef) {

    ElementInfo s1 = heap.get(objRef); // this
    ElementInfo s2 = heap.get(argRef);

    Fields f1 = heap.get(s1.getField("value")).getFields();
    Fields f2 = heap.get(s2.getField("value")).getFields();

    char[] c1 = ((CharArrayFields) f1).asCharArray();
    char[] c2 = ((CharArrayFields) f2).asCharArray();
```

This works fine on Java 8. But in Java 9 and later, the value returned for the `value` field of the String, is either `char[]` or `byte[]`

I expect it to return a byte[] array since the changes made in [JEP 254: Compact Strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254)

---

So for instance:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'a','b','c', 'd'};
String str1 = new String(chars))
"str2".equals(str1);
```

here I get a char array for `str1` and byte array for `"str2"` in the peer method. Is this because that Strings are stored differently in heap?

---

**FYI:**

Here is the code that I'm actually working on. I'm trying to make it work  with Java 9 and later:

[jpf-core/src/peers/gov/nasa/jpf/vm/JPF_java_lang_String.java#L166-L200](https://github.com/javapathfinder/jpf-core/blob/9f076bc2f73a1fc3ad04399376925ef84561dc43/src/peers/gov/nasa/jpf/vm/JPF_java_lang_String.java#L166-L200)

As you may see the `valueField` there is cast to CharArrayFields. But when running on Java "10.0.1", valueField is sometimes a CharArrayFields, and sometimes a ByteArrayFields.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. You said that you *expect* a `byte[]`, and you apparently *get* a `byte[]`. In your example, the type of `str1` *isn't* a `String`, it's actually inherently a `char[]`.

Comment: Additionally, can you confirm an exact JRE version? The code in OpenJDK 10 recodes if you use `new String(char[])`.

Comment: Additionally, if you meant `String str1 = new String(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}); String str2 = "abcd"; System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));`.. both the string are represented as **`byte[]`** to what I could debug using an IDE.

Comment: @chrylis I added a link to the original code.

Comment: it's hard to answer without knowing where these fields come from, and the link does not help - too complex. I suspect that JNI is *transforming* the `byte[]` to `char[]` depending how the bytes are encoded... the String source has no `char[]` field(Java 10.0.2)

Comment: can you please provide 1 string examples for which you are getting char array?

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh he already did : "`String str1 = new String(chars))` ... here I get a char array for str1"

Comment: No, in both cases a string is stored as a byte array in LATIN1 encoding.

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh you did not ask about how it is being stored, but "... examples for which you are getting char array".... and there seems to be some steps (JNI, MJI, ...) inbetween

Comment: Also the char array being returned is correct. So I'll check to see if JNI is transforming the byte array in somewhere.

Comment: All right, this question is now well-defined and weird enough it gets a +1.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thanks for the tip. `value` field of Strings are constructed internally as a char array. It took some digging to find out. You may convert these to an answer.

Comment: @reversiblean untill java 8 value is char array but from  Java 9  value is  byte[] . so just want to know if you are looking at String class in JDK 8 or JDK 9?

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh It's Java 9. The project I'm working on has its own Heap implementation. It assumes `value` field to be a char array. Hence causing problems. It took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: @reversiblean Got it..

Comment: The representation of the Java strings is the same for `"str2"` and `"abcd"`, regardless of how they are constructed. So this is not an issue with Java, but that library you’re using. Besides that, what’s the point of re-implementing what `java.lang.String` already does, besides lots of work and getting inconsistencies like in this question?

Comment: @Holger To my understanding, one reason that it models classes is to be able to inspect/trace native methods.